# Solving combinatoric problem with generating function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I came across this questions:

> Suppose that 10 fish are caught at a lake that contains 5 distinct types of fish. How many different outcomes are possible, where an outcome specifies the numbers of caught fish of each of the 5 types?

I know how the answer is $\binom{10+5-1}{5-1}=4$ This is just [star and bar (type 2 on wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29#Theorem_two) problem with $n=10$ and $r=5$. But I am not able to guess how I can solve the same with generating functions?

I felt it will be coefficient of $x^10$ in $(1+x+x^2+...)^5$. I calculated it as follows:
$(1+x+x^2+...)^5=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{10+j-1}{10-1}x^j$
Coefficient of $x^{10}$ in this is $\binom{10+10-1}{10-1}=\binom{19}{9}=92378$
which definitely does not look correct.

When I checked wolfram alpha [it was saying](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Coefficient+of+x%5E10++in+%281%2F%281-x%29%29%5E5) coefficient of $x^10$ in $(1+x+x^2+...)^5$ is $0$.

Whats going on here?

Comment: ${14 \choose 4} = 1001$, not $4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct generating function here is
$$(1+x+ \cdots + x^{10})^5 = \left(\frac{1-x^{11}}{1-x} \right)^5$$

Now, use

- $\frac{1}{(1-x)^5} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+4}{4}x^n$

You get
$$[x^{10}]\left(\frac{1-x^{11}}{1-x} \right)^5 = [x^{10}]\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+4}{4}x^n = \binom{10+4}{4} = 1001$$

Comment: Yess got my silly mistake. Here if we consider $(1+x+x^2+...)^5$ instead of $(1+x+x^2+...+x^{10} )^5$ we still get same answer. Am wondering when will considering infinite series instead of finite one will give wrong answer?